# Register dll with Jenkins + Octopus

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, octopus-deploy

I want to do deploy a DLL file into the Test environment with Jenkins and Octopus. How can I register the DLL file onto the Test environment straight from Octopus ? Is this the good approach or how can this be achieved ?

The main thing that I want to is that I do not want to run the `regsvr32` instruction in cmd on the test server but instead I want to automate it and run it when the deploy from the Octopus happens.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your Octopus project processes.
Add step (Run a script): You should do this with powershell.
Set your environments if necessary.

Example Powershell:First line is a Powershell command. Second line is executing CMD command on powershell with this:

> & "someprogram.exe" parameters

```
copy-item -Path \\10.0.0.10\DllShareName\myapp.dll -Destination \\10.0.0.11\MyDllTargetFolder
& "C:\windows\system32\regsvr32.exe" myapp.dll
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try it. Thx a lot :D

Comment: One thing to watch out for with running external commands from PS is that OD may not wait for it to complete before it moves to the next step. In this case it probably doesn't matter, but using start-process to run the command instead will avoid that.